# Do seekp() and seekg() perform same function?

Tags: c++

So I know that seekp() is used change the write position and seekg() is used to change the read position but when I use anyone of those while working on a fstream object, it change both read and write position .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 fstream file("input.txt",fstream::in|fstream::out);
file.seekp(0,fstream::end);
file.seekg(0,fstream::beg);
cout << file.tellp() << " " << file.tellg() << endl;
}
```

The output of this code is  " 0 0 " . So why does this happen ?

Comment: `std::fstream` uses a joint file buffer for reading and writing. Using both functions update the same pointers. It makes no difference.

Comment: So you mean I can use seekp() in place of seekg() and viceversa

Comment: On an `std::fstream`, yes.